# Adding to months in array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I've created an array where I increment "25/11/2015" by 1 month. I have a question about how it is working. I'm currently using ***"strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate)"***. I was wondering why in my first row of the array +1month isn't added straight away. Instead I am left with NOV-15 which is what I want but I was **just wondering** why this happens.

currently I'm getting:

Nov-15
Dec-15
Jan-16

why am i not outputting this result:

Dec-15
Jan-16
Feb-16

Heres my code:

```
$date = "2015-11-25";
$start = strtotime($date);

$currentdate = $start;

 $times_table = array();
        for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
            $times_table[$i] = array();

        }
echo "<pre>";

       for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
             for($j = 0; $j <= 4; $j++){

               if ($j == 0){
                $times_table[$i][$j]=  "Version 5" ;
            }
                else if ($j == 1){
                $cur_date = date("M-y", $currentdate);

                $currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);

                $times_table[$i][$j]= $cur_date ;

          echo  $cur_date . ">". "<br />";
                }
                else{
                    $times_table[$i][$j]=  "gary" ;
                }
                if ($j == 3) {
                    $numbers = mt_rand(1, 100);
                    $times_table[$i][$j]= $numbers ;

                }
                if ($j == 4){

                    if($i == 0 || $i == 3)
                    {
                        $pay = "P";

                    $times_table[$i][$j]= $pay ;
                    }
                    else{
                        $int = "I";

                    $times_table[$i][$j]= $int ;

                    }
                }

            }

            }
```

Comment: You have <br/> in echo. If got your point.

Comment: echo  $cur_date . ">". "<br />"; here, you are concatenating '>' and line break, so why do you expect all in a same line?

Comment: Sorry its outputted incorrectly my question was at the moment my array starts with NOV-15 but why doesn't straight away add 1 to the date making it DEC-15

Answer (score 0):

What you write is what you get:

```
$cur_date = date("M-y", $currentdate);
$currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);
$times_table[$i][$j]= $cur_date ;
```

You set the $currentdate value to $cur_date before one month was added, and then store the $cur_date value. This is the reason why it doesnt add 1 month straight away (it is added straight away to $currentdate but not to $cur_date)